# Extract more than 250 orders in a day using shopify orders API

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-api

I'm using Shopify API to get orders data(Order Name, UTM parameters etc) but the thing is API is restricted to 250 orders by default. I came to know that the response header contains a parameter link which has page_info which can be used to paginate and iterate to obtain all the orders but the thing is even using all this, I'm not able to obtain details of all the orders(for some reason, few orders are getting skipped. Not sure whether it only fetches fulfilled orders or it has any such default filter). Other problem with pagination is that one can only have page_info and rel as the only parameters while paginating. The end goal is to obtain all the orders(irrespective of what happened to the order later on)

Here is the code that I've used

```
orders = []
#Here, I'm defining the date for which I want to get the orders for
params = {'created_at_min': '2023-05-11T00:00:00%2B05:30', 'created_at_max': '2023-05-11T23:59:59%2B05:30', 'limit': '250'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=params)
for item in response.json()['orders']:
  orders.append(item['name'])
print(len(orders))
for i in range(0,100):
    try:
        #obtaining the page_info(we'll get this only if there are more than 250 orders)
        next_page = response.headers['Link']
        #print(next_page)
        start = "page_info="
        end = ">"
        #just some string extraction to get the page_info part, you can ignore this
        start_escaped = re.escape(start)
        end_escaped = re.escape(end)
        result = re.search(f"(?<={start_escaped}).*(?={end_escaped})", next_page).group()
        print(result)
        params = {'page_info':result,'rel':'next','limit':'250'}
        print(params)
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=params)
        print(len(response.json()['orders']))
        if len(response.json()['orders'])<250:
            for item in response.json()['orders']:
                orders.append(item['name'])
            break

    except:
        print('failed')
        break
orders= pd.DataFrame(orders,columns=["Order ID"])
```

Answer (score 1):

In the query params you need to pass `'status': 'any'` (https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/order#get-orders?status=any) some orders are skipped in default settings of the API GET Request